# mixing of pattern matching and date time functions in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, pattern-matching, sql-server-group-concat, sql-like

I have problem mixing pattern match and curdate() function.  Below is the table structure, where some of the fields current date is updated everyday. I am not sure whether they can be mixed.Please help me sort this out. Thanks.

```
  ta1           ta2        ta3      ta4
a20120204     20120204  20120204  20120203
a20120204123  20120204  20120203  20120203
```

I want my like pattern to be 'a20120204', which is current date prefixed by character 'a'.

My non-working intuitive query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ta1 LIKE 'a'+(CURDATE( ) +0)%
```

- (CURDATE()+0) returns current date as YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it - the function you're after is [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), which concatenates strings together:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE ta1 LIKE CONCAT('a',(CURDATE()+0),'%');
```

Note - `CONCAT('a','b','%')` gives 'ab%', etc.